# Empty menus in emacs

Tags: ubuntu, troubleshooting, emacs

I am using emacs-snapshot on Ubuntu 11.04.

In some of the emacs modes, like Auctex and ESS, the menus have no contents, i.e. in Auctex when I click on the Preview, Latex, or Command menus, a small empty rectangle appears. The standard menus (File, Edit, Options, Buffers, Tools) have regular contents.

This has occurred around the same time as updating from Ubuntu 10.04 to 11.04, but I am not sure if they are related.

The problem does not occur using emacs-23.

How can I get the menus back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a valid Ubuntu bug: [Bug #415101](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emacs23/+bug/415101). The workaround is to set variable `GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1` before running emacs.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the bug - my experience - reflected in the comments of that bug - indicate that this fix does not work. The menus do open with F10, however. It also indicates that the bug is with all flavors of emacs, not just emacs-snapshot, but I only get the bug with emacs-snapshot (perhaps because the bug has been fixed in emacs23).

Answer (score 5):

Although this is a currently unresolved bug (as pointed out by @sindikat), the menus can be accessed with F10.

Comment: I also run into this bug in openSUSE 42.  Hitting F10 works. Where should I report it - openSUSE bugtracker or is it a emacs bug?

Comment: Wow this bug is still present in the version of Emacs 25 (GTK+ version) packaged for Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty).  And the workaround still works; just press F10 once and it fixes those empty menus (presumably refreshes them)